# How to view attachments in Thunderbird that are in outlook .msg format?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, thunderbird

My colleague receives regularly e-mails that contain attachments that are in outlook .msg format. She is using Thunderbird on an Ubuntu desktop. The trouble is that Thunderbird can not show such attachments out of the box. It appears that there is a perl script that can can convert .msg files from a command line. However, she is not skilled to work with command line. Is there any way to make Thunderbird to view .msg files without involving the command line?

Answer (score 0):

For basic file access you can select file form the hamberger menu option. You will then need to set the filter to all files and open the .msg file.

What I want to know is how to set this up an association so I can just view .msg files. What are the command line parameters to open an .msg file